# Joomla 3.1.5 Saving tags to ucm_content and contentitem_tag_map

Tags: tags, save, joomla3.1

I have spent days on this one so I have put my hand up. I am implementing tags in my own component and have followed Elin's instructions on the Joomla site to the letter (27 July 2013). I can get the new tags to save in the TAGS table correctly, but not the UCM or TAG MAP tables as all the standard components do.
I have traced the code all the way through, and compared to the com_contacts, and cannot for the life of me see any difference in my component.
Where should I be looking for where the code updates the other two tables? I know this will end in an embarrassing answer but I am happy to look foolish.
My table does not have meta fields, but I have manually fudged the metadata array in the $data array. Any help is appreciated.

Instructions:http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension

Answer (score 2):

After many days of extra frustration I discovered that for my component I had to include the archived information into my table class, that is not supposed to be required any more.

Add a property

```
    /**
     * Indicator that the tags have been changed
     *
     * @var    JHelperTags
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $tagsHelper = null;
```

This property helps to manage change in tags.
Modify your constructor

Follow this example to modify your consructor which provides substantial reduction in duplicate code.

```
            $this->tagsHelper = new JHelperTags();
            $this->tagsHelper->typeAlias = 'com_contact.contact';
```

Modify your store() method

Management of tagging and associated data is largely handled through the store() method. This provides maximum flexibility for the handling of tags across many extensions.

If you don't have a store() method you will need to add one. The assumption is that tables will inherit from JTable.

The handling involves preStoreProcess(), a call to the parent store() method, and then a postStoreProcess().

```
            $this->tagsHelper->preStoreProcess($this);
            $result = parent::store($updateNulls);

            return $result && $this->tagsHelper->postStoreProcess($this);
```

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension is the current Joomla instructions. Click on History to take you back to the 8 July version.

Comment: Content not displaying in the tags page. It is to set core_state to 1. How to set that in table file?